# Cyclic relationships in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, relationship

I want to map a tree in hibernate, but persisting it results in an exception because of the cyclic reference (the relationships are not bidirectional).

```
class Node {
    @ManyToOne
    Node parent;

    @OneToOne
    Node leftChild;

    @OneToOne
    Node rightChild;
}
```

Node N references its left child L which in turn references N again as its parent. Also, node N references its right child R which in turn again references N again as parent. However, I cannot make the relationships bidirectional, because parent would be the inverse of both leftChild and rightChild. What is the best way to make this model persistable?

Regards,
Jochen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem:

```
@Entity
class Node {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Node parent;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Node leftChild;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Node rightChild;

    Node() {}

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // omitted getters and setters for brevity
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                  .addAnnotatedClass(Node.class)
                  .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",
                      "jdbc:h2:mem:foo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
                  .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")
                  .buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Node a = new Node("A");
    Node b = new Node("B");
    Node c = new Node("C");
    Node d = new Node("D");
    Node e = new Node("E");
    a.setLeftChild(b);
    b.setParent(a);
    a.setRightChild(c);
    c.setParent(a);
    b.setLeftChild(d);
    d.setParent(b);
    b.setRightChild(e);
    e.setParent(b);
    System.out.println("Before saving:");
    print(a, 1);
    Serializable rootNodeId = session.save(a);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Node root = (Node) session.load(Node.class, rootNodeId);
    System.out.println("Freshly loaded:");
    print(root, 1);
    session.close();
}

private static void print(Node node, int depth) {
    if (node == null) { return; }
    System.out.format("%" + depth + "s\n", node);
    print(node.getLeftChild(), depth + 1);
    print(node.getRightChild(), depth + 1);
}
```

Comment: Works with Hibernate 4.3.11. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for Hibernate to distinguish left and right child in your example. Regardless of Hibernate, given two rows in the database that have reference to parent, how do you distinguish left and right?  So, if you have multiple entries in the same table that refer to parent, you are actually having `OneToMany` from parent to children nodes. Therefore, I recommend that you model it as `@OneToMany`. Then, if necessary, provide some transient getters that will distinguish left child vs right child in the list of children via some additional logic.